# Docker container not running after creating with mounted volume

Tags: docker, containers, volume

I am trying to use an image that I pulled from the docker database. However I need data from the host to use some programs loaded into the image. I created a container with this

```
sudo docker run --name="mdrap" -v "/home/ubuntu/profile/reads/SE:/usr/local/src/volume" sigenae/drap
```

it appears that everything works and then I start the container

```
sudo docker start mdrap
```

but when I check the running containers it is not listed there and if I try to load the container into /bin/bash it tells me the container is not running. I am a beginner with docker and am only trying to use an image to run programs with all the required dependencies, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`docker start` is only to start a stopped container. It's not necessary after a `docker run`. (but more after a `docker **create**`, like in [the documentation](http://www.sigenae.org/drap/install.html))

A container is started as long as it's main process is running.
As soon as the main process stops, the container stops.

The main process of a container can be either:

- the `ENTRYPOINT` if defined
- the `CMD` if no `ENTRYPOINT` and no command line argument
- the command line argument

In your case, as you don't have any command line argument (after the image name on the `docker run` command) and the image only defines a `CMD` (=`/bin/bash`), your container is trying to start a `/bin/bash`.
**But**, as you don't launch the container with the `--interactive/-i` nor `--tty/-t` (again like in [the documentation](http://www.sigenae.org/drap/install.html)), your process as nothing to interact with and stops (idem for each start of this container).

So your solution is simply to follow [the documentation](http://www.sigenae.org/drap/install.html):

```
docker create --name drap --privileged -v /home/ubuntu/profile/reads/SE:/usr/local/src/volume -i -t sigenae/drap /bin/bash
docker start drap
docker exec -i -t drap /bin/bash
```

Or even simpler:

```
docker run --name drap --privileged -v /home/ubuntu/profile/reads/SE:/usr/local/src/volume -i -t sigenae/drap /bin/bash
```

Comment: Thank you I'm a super beginner just trying to use a program but this worked totally